# Dynamics of this NOT EXISTS statement

Tags: sqlite, not-exists

I have this table tab1 and want to select latest record for each user.

| user | date | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| brad | 2/4/2015 | 1.1 |
| fred | 3/6/2012 | 1.0 |
| bob | 4/8/2019 | 1.5 |
| brad | 2/10/2015 | 1.2 |
| fred | 3/4/2013 | 1.3 |
| fred | 3/24/2013 | 1.1 |

brad | 2/10/2015

fred | 3/24/2013

bob  | 4/8/2019

I'm having trouble understanding this query.

```
select *
FROM tab1 where not exists (select * from tab1 t where t.date < tab1.date and tab1.user = t.user);
```

Oddly, I am getting correct results from this- How is using min(date) giving the latest date?

```
select user, min(date) from tab1 group by user
```

Comment: `min(date)` shouldn't give the latest date, it should return the earliest date.

Comment: What is the datatype of `date`? If it's VARCHAR, the values are being compared as strings, not dates. `3/24` is less than `3/4` and `3/6` when treated as strings.

Comment: You need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert the strings to dates so you can compare them properly.

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` query also returns the earliest date. It returns any row where there's no other row with the same user and an earlier date.

Comment: @Barmar It's a TIME column in sqlite

Comment: Then neither of your queries should work to get the latest date, they both get the oldest date.

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD so that they are comparable. Then explain what you want to do.